# What does the stl find function return from deque

Tags: c++, c++14, deque

I'm having a std deque and searching for elements in it. My problem is that I do not understand what kind of form is the find function returning.

```
std::deque< DataCellHandle > dataCellHandleArray;
std::_Deque_iterator<DataCellHandle, const DataCellHandle&, const DataCellHandle*> it =
    std::find( dataCellHandleArray.cbegin(), dataCellHandleArray.cend(), releaseHandle ); // works

std::deque< DataCellHandle >::iterator itr =
    std::find( dataCellHandleArray.cbegin(), dataCellHandleArray.cend(), releaseHandle ); // does not work
```

I expected that either a index or a iterator will be returned.

Comment: Don't touch types with names `_Like _These`. Those are standard library implementation details, and are not portable. All such names are off limits to application code.

Comment: I know that is not the best idea. I wanted just to show that I was testing my stuff, but in the end it was a major oversight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of `std::find` is identical to the type of the iterators you instantiate this function template with. In your case, you pass `dataCellHandleArray.cbegin()` and `.cend()`, which is of type `std::deque::const_iterator`, not `std::deque::iterator`. Hence, this is your fix:

```
std::deque<DataCellHandle>::const_iterator it = ...
```

Note that this works out of the box with:

```
auto it = std::find(dataCellHandleArray.cbegin(), dataCellHandleArray.cend(),
   releaseHandle);
```

Note that a `const_iterator` can be constructed from an `iterator`, but not the inverse.

```
// Ok, iterator to const_iterator
std::deque<DataCellHandle>::const_iterator ci = dataCellHandleArray.begin();

// Ok, compare const_iterator and iterator:
assert(ataCellHandleArray.begin() == ataCellHandleArray.cbegin());

// Error, can't loose constness of the "pointee"
std::deque<DataCellHandle>::iterator ci = dataCellHandleArray.cbegin();
```

Comment: Now I see what oversight i made. Thxn for the fast response.

Answer (score 6):

[`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns object of the same type as `first` and `last` argument, which in your case is **`std::deque<DataCellHandle>::const_iterator`**